# Как узнать имена всех файлов в папке?

Tags: lua, luajit

К примеру у меня есть папка, в ней есть файлы(точное количество я не знаю файлов). Мне надо узнать название каждого файла с его расширением. Использовать какие-то библиотеки мне не надо. Пример: [image: пример файлов]

Comment: Значит нужно открыть документацию и читать, читать, читать. Пока не узнаете, как это делать, гляньте например в сторону `lfs`.

Answer (score 2):

Как видите, в разделах про
[работу с файлами](https://www.lua.org/work/doc/manual.html#6.8)
и
[средства ОС](https://www.lua.org/work/doc/manual.html#6.9)
ничего про чтение директорий нету.  Так что прямой ответ на ваш
вопрос — **нельзя**, по крайне мере
без костылей с `popen`.

На АнглоСО есть
[вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5303174/1892060)
со множеством вариантов ответов, в том числе через `popen`
и внешние библиотеки.  Также, в книге *Programming In Lua* есть
[глава](https://www.lua.org/pil/29.html)
про создание итератора директорий через *C API*.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже было сказано: дефолтными средствами `lua` это не сделать. Но есть очень хорошая (и распространенная) библиотека `lfs`. Например для того, чтобы получить все имена файлов в текущей директории можно сделать так:

```lua
local lfs = require("lfs")

for entry in lfs.dir(".") do
  local mode = lfs.attributes("./" .. entry, "mode")
  if (mode == "file") then
    print(entry, mode)
  end
end
```

Comment: Более подробно о библиотеке на странице автора https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/

Answer (score 0):

Специфичного для русской винды ответа на этот вопрос на англоСО нет, поэтому он должен быть здесь )))
Кодировка строк (путь к папке и возвращаемые имена файлов) - win1251

```
local dir_path = [[C:\путь\к\папке\]]
local dir = io.popen('chcp 1251|dir /a-d /b "'..dir_path..'"')
for filename in dir:lines() do
   print(filename)
end
dir:close()
```

Comment: вряд ли этот ответ можно счесть полезным из-за крайней привязки к системе и такой платформо-зависимой вещи как `popen`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch - вы правы, мой ответ не претендует на кроссплатформенность, он решает только конкретную проблему, возникшую у автора вопроса (у него винда).  Пользователям других ОС рекомендуется поискать ответ на англоязычном СО, поскольку их ситуация не требует подхода, специфичного для русскоязычности.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch - а насчёт popen замечу, что обычно там, где не доступен popen, загрузка внешних бинарных модулей (типа lfs) тоже недоступна.

Comment: не знал об этом - пруфы какие-нибудь есть?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch - пруф - это исходники Lua.  Загрузка внешних бинарных библиотек - это в принципе некроссплатформенная вещь, и в Lua она реализована только для Win, POSIX и MacOS. А popen - это простая функция из Сишной библиотеки, которая точно присутствует в трёх перечисленных ОС и, возможно, есть ещё в каких-то других ОС.